# How to get selected items of Listbox control?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I am developing an application in ASP.NET & c#. I have a Grid view in my page. In that I have a **Listbox** control and by default **Enabled** property set by **false**. I am trying to enable & disable that control from javascript / jQuery on **Checkbox** control.

**My ASP Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvWhom" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsWhom"
GridLines="None" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gvWhom_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr style="height: 25px;">
        <td width="20%">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCriteria" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TargetType") %>' />
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbCriteria" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" Width="150px" Height="50px"
            Enabled="false" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
        </td>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Height="2px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function disableDropDown(chkCriteria, lbCriteria) {
    if (document.getElementById(chkCriteria).checked) {         
     document.getElementById(lbCriteria).removeAttribute('disabled');
    }else{
     document.getElementById(lbCriteria).value = -1;
     document.getElementById(lbCriteria).disabled = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void gvWhom_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    ListBox lbCriteria = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("lbCriteria");
    CheckBox chkCriteria = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkCriteria");
    chkCriteria.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:return disableDropDown('" + chkCriteria.ClientID + "', '" + lbCriteria.ClientID + "')");
    }
}
```

Using above code I am able to enable / disable the Listbox control. But when I enable the control and select multiple items and submitting the form I am not able to find **selected items** of Listbox.

How can I fetch selected items of Listbox? or Is there any other way to enable - disable the listbox control and get the selected items in c# code?

Comment: My guess would be that ASP.NET is ignoring it because it's disabled.  Changing it on the client-side may be too late because the framework already decided to detach it from view state.  What happens if you don't disable it in the control markup and instead disable it immediately in JavaScript when the document renders?  Then continue enabling/disabling as needed in JavaScript.  From the server's perspective it would "expect" it to be enabled and would track it like the other controls.

Comment: @David Can you explain with some code? I have no issues if I have to do it on page load. My aim is to enable - disable that control.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a guess, but it's worth a try...

You're disabling the control on the server-side here:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbCriteria" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" Width="150px" Height="50px"
        Enabled="false" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

That `Enabled="false"` may be indicating to ASP.NET that it doesn't need to track this control, that changes won't be made to it.  That *might* be why it's not getting the data back when you post back to the server.

Let's try keeping the control enabled from the server's (ASP.NET's) perspective, and maintaining the enabling/disabling in the UI entirely on the client's (JavaScript's) side.  Essentially removing ASP.NET's built-in framework from making decisions for you regarding what data to track.

Start by enabling the control in the server-side control markup:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbCriteria" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" Width="150px" Height="50px"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

The rest is handled by JavaScript.  You already have some JavaScript code which you say enables/disabled the control on the client-side for you, correct?  So all you need to do now is call that same JavaScript for every instance of the control when the page first loads in the browser to disable the controls client-side.  This is the part you want:

```
document.getElementById(lbCriteria).value = -1;
document.getElementById(lbCriteria).disabled = true;
```

Now, it looks like you're binding your JavaScript events from the server-side code, which is where I won't be able to help as much because that method isn't particularly intuitive to me.  (It's mixing JavaScript and C#, which feels a bit backwards.)  So I'm not *entirely* sure the approach you'd take there.

Essentially you want to invoke those two lines of JavaScript for every instance of the control, and you want it to happen as soon as the page loads in the browser.

In jQuery I'd do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('select.ddl').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This would run when the DOM is loaded and would add the `disabled` attribute (with a value of `"disabled"` to every `select` with the class `ddl`.